# Изображение на весь экран при клике

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть вот такой код

```
<div class="image" id="image" style="background-image:url('...')"></div>
```

Мне нужно чтобы при клике на этот див вылазило модальное окно на весь экран (или почти на весь, главное чтобы большого размера) с изображением, которое находится внутри этого дива.
Как это можно реализовать? Без разницы подключая ли js или можно через css, не имеет значения.

Comment: Это можно реализовать готовым лайтбоксом, который гуглится за пару минут, под любую популярную CMS (а если сайт без CMS, то из свободных плагинов можно скопипастить содержимое и поменять классы/айди).

Answer (score 1):

Вот тебе на js и без подключения каких-либо библиотек.

```
var image = document.querySelector('.image');

image.addEventListener(click, function() {
  image.classList.toggle('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение jQuery, взято с [официального сайта](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/):

```
$( "#foo" ).toggleClass( className, addOrRemove );
```

И проверка:

```
if ( addOrRemove ) {
  $( "#foo" ).addClass( className );
} else {
  $( "#foo" ).removeClass( className );
}
```